# Git pushing folders but it gets push as a file

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I am trying to push my android code of two app residing in two different folders into a repository using gitbash but after pushing all the changes when I check them on bitbucket I see two files with the same name something like this (please refer the screenshot)
[image]

The steps Which I followed:

1. Created a Repository.
2. git clone.
3. then copied my folders to the folder Which I got after clone.
4. through git bash move to the cloned directory.
5. git add -A
6. git commit -m 'some message'
7. git push origin master.

I dont know what I am doing wrong ? What can be the possible reason behind that.

Comment: What was the expected contents of your Bitbucket repository?

Comment: Two folders with its content. @nonsensickle

Comment: What branch are you currently on? Are you working on `master`? Check with `git status`.

Comment: That's master branch